# Native NPAPI plugin isn't loaded by Firefox Beta 4

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom, npapi, firefox4

I've been scratching my head over this for the last few days and neither me nor Google have come up with a good solution.

I have a native NPAPI plugin that works fine for Firefox 3.6. It simply consists of a single np*.dll, nothing else.

Now I'm upgrading it to Firefox 4 Beta. I've changed the install.rdf to include the new em:unpack directive (XPIs were automatically unpacked in Pre-4) and even added a new chrome.manifest with the (supposedly) now required 'binary-component' statement (according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0: 'Prior to Gecko 2, during component registration, all binary and JavaScript component files were loaded and called, asking them to register themselves').

The problem is: The plugin downloads and supposedly installs. But then while it shows up in the AddOn manager it doesn't show up in 'about:plugins' and is of course not usable either. I ran Firefox with extension logging enabled but nothing really useful regarding the plugin showed up there either..

Basically I'm stumped - any help please?

Comment: does it work if you install it as a plugin instead of as an extension?

Comment: yes, it does - I copied the np*.dll manually into the plugin folder and it worked just like in 3.6. In the meantime I actually grabbed the latest Firefox 4 source and compiled a debug version. If I'm installing via XPI the DLL is loaded, but only for the XPCOM stuff. It used to be in Firefox Pre-4 that it would automatically load the DLL & call the appropriate NSAPI NP_Initialize/NP_GetEntryPoints. Maybe that functionality is gone in 4?

Comment: I guess worst case I could write an XPCOM DLL as well that 'stuffs' the NPAPI DLL into the proper plugins directory... but that seems a bit hackisch. :-)

Comment: well, if you were going to do that it'd make a lot more sense to just add the appropriate registry entry so it'd find the NPAPI dll where it is, rather than trying to put it in the plugins directory =] These are the sort of issues that cause me to recommend FireBreath users to install using an MSI instead of an XPI.  I hope someone finds a good answer for you, though :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phew - turns out I found the cause of the problem: the np*.dll was in the root folder inside the XPI, not in the plugins/ folder as it's supposed to be. FF3.6 was more forgiving it seems, FF4 only loads a NPAPI DLL if the DLL is actually inside the plugins folder...

Problem solved :-)